# How to transform a flat array-like sequence to an associative map?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Essentially, I want an equivalent of this Python function in JavaScript:

```
def to_dict(coll, key):
    return {i[key]: i for i in coll}

assert to_dict([
    {'key': 1, 'value': 1},
    {'key': 2, 'value': 2},
    {'key': 3, 'value': 3},
], 'key') == {
    1: {'key': 1, 'value': 1},
    2: {'key': 2, 'value': 2},
    3: {'key': 3, 'value': 3},
}
```

I know I can construct it by hand, but is there a concise way? (jQuery or Underscore.js can be used)

Answer (score 1):

```
function to_dict(coll, key) {
   var obj = {};
   //Unsafe to use iterator on array in JavaScript
   for (var i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
      obj[coll[i][key]] = coll[i];
   }
   return obj;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R7hfX/

Comment: @AlexB - I prefer constructing it by hand. It executes faster than jQuery and Underscore, but if you really want to use a library I suggest you use [Vapor.js](http://vaporjs.com/ "Vapor.js | The World's Smallest &amp; Fastest JavaScript Library"). In either case the code is essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

untested:

```
var to_dict = function (arr, key)
{
  return _.reduce(
    arr
  , function (rv, v) { rv[v[key]] = v; return rv; }
  , {}
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery .. this is slightly more elegant

```
function to_dict(coll, key) {
    var obj = {}
    $.each(coll, function () {
        obj[this[key]] = this;
    });
    return obj;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R7hfX/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = {}
for (var x in d) {
    if (d.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        t[d[x].key] = d[x];
    }
}
```